# Windows Server 2016 not Seeing VM on Azure

Tags: networking, azure, windows-server-2016, discovery

I have windows Server 2016, and a Windows 10 Workstation on azure, I’m trying to map a drive from the workstation to Windows Server 2016 or vice versus.
Problem:  Windows Server 2016, is not seeing vm1 on Domain Network even though it is on 
Domain and is able to ping.

Screenshots of IPCONFIG/all of each computer, Pinging,
network connections

DOMAIN CONTROLER, IPADDRESS 10.0.0.4

VM, IPADDRESS 10.0.0.6

[Domain Controller ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPQqY.png)
[VM ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWmQJ.png)
[Pinging DC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcNsq.png)
[Network Connection to Domain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJsBj.png)
[Screenshot Server1/Network Connections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FB6lb.png)

What I've already done
[Network Discovery Turned On](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8cr2.png)
[DNS client in Services   ON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZctLi.png)
[Function Discovery       ON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJGxe.png)

I've take down the Firewall on both Server 2016 and the VM.
On the VM side i'm running. 
Windows 10
Version 1803 (OS Build 17134.1006)

On the Server Side I'm running
Windows Server 2016
Version 1607
(OS Build 14393.3204)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the machines to "see" each other to map a drive. If you have a shared folder on either machine then map it from the other machine with the net use command:

```
net use X: \\computername\sharename /persistent:yes
```

Comment: Okay that makes sense, I'll try that it a minute.  For instance though what would my solution be if I wanted the computers to see each other in the Network drop-down menu in the File Explorer.